# A Haskell function is higher order if and only if its type has more than one arrow?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

A professor teaching a class I am attending claimed the following.

> A higher-order function could have only one arrow when checking its type.

I don't agree with this statement I tried to prove it is wrong. I tried to set up some function but then I found that my functions probably aren't higher-order functions. Here is what I have:

```
f x y z = x + y + z
f :: a -> a->  a -> a

g = f 3
g :: a -> a -> a

h = g 5
h :: a -> a
```

At the end of the day, I think my proof was wrong, but I am still not convinced that higher-order functions can only have more than one arrow when checking the type.

So, is there any resource or perhaps someone could prove that higher-order function may have only one arrow?

Comment: A higher order function is either the one taking another function as argument or returning another function. So if we accept that `a` can only designate a non-function types (which is not necessarily true) then your professor is right.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, the statement is correct. This is because the usual definition of the term "higher-order function", taken here from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), is a function that does one or both of the following:

- takes a function as an argument, or
- returns a function as its result

It is clear then that no function with a single arrow in its type signature can be a higher-order function, because in a signature `a -> b`, there is no "room" to create something of the form `x -> y` on either side of an arrow - there simply aren't enough arrows.

(This argument actually has a significant flaw, which you may have spotted, and which I'll address below. But it's probably true "in spirit" for what your professor meant.)

The converse is also, strictly speaking, true in Haskell - although not in most other languages. The distinguishing feature of Haskell here is that functions are *curried*. For example, a function like `(+)`, whose signature is:

```
a -> a -> a
```

(with a `Num a` constraint that I'll ignore because it could just confuse the issue if we're supposed to be counting "arrows"), is usually thought of as being a function of two arguments: it takes 2 `a`s and produces another `a`. In most languages, which all of course have an analagous function/operator, this would never be described as a higher-order function. But in Haskell, because functions are curried, the above signature is really just a shorthand for the parenthesised version:

```
a -> (a -> a)
```

which clearly *is* a higher-order function. It takes an `a` and produces a function of type `a -> a`. (Recall, from above, that returning a function is one of the things that characterises a HOF.) In Haskell, as I said, these two signatures are one and the same thing. `(+)` really *is* a higher-order function - we just often don't notice that because we intend to feed it two arguments, by which we really mean to feed it one argument, result in a function, then feed *that* function the second argument. Thanks to Haskell's convenient, parenthesis-free, syntax for applying functions to arguments, there isn't really any distinction. (This again contrasts from non-functional languages: the addition "function" there always takes exactly 2 arguments, and only giving it one will usually be an error. If the language has first-class functions, you can indeed define the curried form, for example this in Python:

```
def curried_add(x):
    return lambda y: x + y
```

but this is clearly a different function from the straightforward function of two arguments that you would normally use, and usually less convenient to apply because you need to call it as `curried_add(x)(y)` rather than just say `add(x,y)`.

So, if we take currying into account, the statement of your professor is strictly true.

Well, with the following exception, which I alluded to above. I've been assuming that something with a signature of the form

```
a -> b
```

is not a HOF*. That of course doesn't apply if `a` or `b` is a function. Often, that function's type will include an arrow, and we're tacitly assuming here that neither `a` or `b` contains arrows. Well, Haskell has type synonyms, so we could easily define, say:

```
type MyFunctionType = Int -> Int
```

and then a function with signature `MyFunctionType -> a` or `a -> MyFunctionType` is most certainly a HOF, even though it doesn't "look like one" from just a glance at the signature.

*To be clear here,`a` and `b` refer to specific types which are as yet unspecified - I am not referring to an actual signature `a -> b` which would mean a polymorphic function that applies to *any* types `a` and `b`, which would not necessarily be functions.

Comment: If `f :: a -> b`, then even though `a` or `b` could be instantiated to a function type in a particular call of `f`, `f`'s implementation cannot make use of the fact that it's operating on functions for that call. So I wouldn't call a polymorphic function with only one arrow higher-order, just because it could be instantiated to work on functions, any more than I would call it a string function just because it could be instantiated to work on strings. We statically know that it cannot do anything "functiony" or "stringy" with values of those types.

Comment: Agreed @Ben, and perhaps I misled - my use of type variables like `a` and `b` in that last section wasn't supposed to be referring to polymorphic functions, but I had in mind that `a` and `b` are more like "placeholders" that would be replaced by a particular type. And if that type happens to be a function type, even one that, due to a type synonym, isn't "obviously" a function type, then I am saying that we would still have a HOF, despite there being only one explicit arrow in the type signature.

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you're saying now, that's an important clarification. Sorry I misunderstood. I sometimes use capitalised identifiers for placeholders like that to avoid confusion with polymorphic variables, but then it's confusible that I'm talking about specific types instead.

Comment: No problem at all, I should have been more careful, given that usually in Haskell things like `a -> b` do indeed mean polymorphic types. I'll try to edit to make that clearer, but either way I think this is a useful discussion/clarification, so thanks for raising it!

Comment: Tiny nitpick: `Int -> Proxy (Int -> Int)` is a function type that has two arrows, but it is not the type of a higher-order function.

Comment: Fair point @DanielWagner, I guess I should clarify it to rule out a function type being applied as an argument to a higher-kinded type :)

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are higher order. Indeed, take for example your function:

```
f :: a -> a -> a -> a
f x y z = x + y + z
```

This is a less verbose form of:

```
f :: a -> (a -> (a -> a))
```

So it is a function that takes an `a` and *returns a function*. A higher order function is a function that (a) takes a function as parameter, or (b) returns a function. Both can be true at the same time. Here your function `f` returns a function.

A function thus always has type `a -> b` with `a` the input type, and `b` the return type. In case `a` has an arrow (like `(c -> d) -> b`), then it is a higher order function, since it takes a function as parameter.

If `b` has an arrow, like `a -> (c -> d)`, then this is a higher order function as well, since it returns a function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Haskell functions are curried always, I can come up with minimal examples of higher order functions and examples:

1) Functions that takes a function at least as parameter, such as:

```
apply :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
apply f x = f x
```

2) at least 3 arguments:

```
sum3 :: Int -> Int -> Int
sum3 a b c = a + b + c
```

so that can be read as:

```
sum3 :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```